# float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

I have code:

```
  a = int(input("Type a integer："))
    temp = []
    while a != 1:
  --->   for i in range(2, a):
            if a % i == 0:
                temp.append(i)
                a = a / i
                break
    print(temp)
```

I typed 60 and then it gives the error: 
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

However, I checked:

```
a = int(input("Type a integer"))
type(a)
```

It shows type of a is int.

If so, where is the float type comes from?

Comment: You're dividing! `a` will become a float if it's not divisible by `i` (creating fractional parts).

Comment: `a = a // i` if you want integer division

Answer (score 4):

When you divide `a` by `i`, it becomes a decimal number after so many iterations. If you started with 60, then the operations would follow like this:

```
a = 60 / 2     (=30)
a = 30 / 3     (=10)
a = 10 / 4     (=2.5)
```

Now, we can see that `a` is trying to be a float when you told it to be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide it by a number , it become a float , you can return it to integer by :

```
a = int(a)
```

after

```
a = a/i
```

Or :

```
 a = a//i
```

Answer (score 1):

The float comes from using float division a/i.  To get an int use integer division a//i