# Python2.7 TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I just fork clone a repo inconvergent/hyphae on github to reuse [hyphae.py](https://github.com/inconvergent/hyphae/blob/master/hyphae.py) with an update from python2.6 to python2.7 (and then 3.5) I fixed some error due to update but i still have `TypeError` for now.

**Done**

Update from `python2.6` to `pyton2.7.13` by adding `()` after all `print`

Fix

```
File "/home/user/hyphae/hyphae.py", line 378
main()
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

By adding 2 whitespace

When do `python2.7 /home/user/hyphae/hyphae.py`
 with terminal

```
()
('filename', 'generations_a')
('SIZE', 15000)
('ZONEWIDTH', 80.0)
('RAD', 0.002666666666666667)
('ZONES', 187)
('one', 6.666666666666667e-05)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/hyphae/hyphae.py", line 378, in <module>
main()
File "/home/user/hyphae/hyphae.py", line 203, in main
R = np.zeros(NMAX,'float')
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

I not that few questions were asked about `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index` in stackoverflow, e.g [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621412/float-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer) ot [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355608/python-typeerror-float-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer), but as the noob as i'm, i don't find how to solve the matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
NMAX = 2*1e7 # maxmimum number of nodes
```

NMAX is a floating point number. In older versions of numpy, you can call `zeros` with a float as an argument. But this behavior is deprecated, and no longer works in the most recent version.

Try converting NMAX to an integer.

```
NMAX = int(2*1e7) # maxmimum number of nodes
```